# How to check if a String is contained in another String in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible to check if a `String` is contained in another `String` in Java?

It would be the inverse of what the [contains method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) accomplishes.

Example:

```
final String testStr = "Some String.";
final String fullString = "This text contains Some String.";
if (testStr.isContained(fullString)) {
    // Your logic.
}
```

In my real use case, I have the following code:

```
final String testStr = anyMethod(); // null is a possibility here.
if (testStr.contains(AnyClass.STRING_CONSTANT) {
    // Your logic here.
}
```

Since `testStr` can be `null` and I'm always comparing it to a [constant](/questions/tagged/constant), I tried to reverse the comparison in order to avoid [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) or to be forced to compare `testStr` against `null` first.

Comment: `fullString.contains(testStr)`?

Comment: @Turing85, I asked this question because in my real use case scenario `testStr` is a constant, which, obviously, is never `null`, and `fullString` may be null and I was trying to avoid NPE. Maybe it would be easier to check for nullity.

Comment: Well... `Optional.ofNullable(fullString).orElse("").contains(testStr);`

Comment: Shouldn't that, and any other key information, be in the question itself?

Comment: Thank you, and I updated it some more. Best to only have problem specific information in the question without meta information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to check if a `String` is contained in another `String` in Java?*
>
> *It would be the opposite of the [contains method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) accomplishes.
> ..."*

For logic; a completely valid question.

By the way, technically you mean the "inverse", rather.
The "opposite" would be if the value does not contain the other value.

So, if *testStr* is within *fullString*, and not if *fullString* contains *testStr*.

Just write a *isContained* method, to qualify the condition.

```java
boolean isContained(String substring, String string) {
    return string.contains(substring);
}
```

And, if you want to ignore the case, you can use the following.

```java
boolean isContained(String substring, String string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().contains(substring.toLowerCase());
}
```

So, here is a usage.

```java
final String testStr = "Some String.";
final String fullString = "This text contains Some String.";
if (isContained(testStr, fullString)) {
    // Your logic.
}
```

Furthermore, you're saying that *testStr* may be *null*.

In this case, just provide a check before-hand, to avoid the *NullPointerException*.

```java
boolean isContained(String substring, String string) {
    if (string == null || substring == null) return false;
    return string.contains(substring);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fullstring.contains(testStr)
```

To avoid `NullPointerException`s, use an `if` statement and `&&` operator:

```
if (fullstring != null && fullstring.contains(testStr)) {
    // your logic
}
```

If `fullstring` is null, the second part won't execute.

Edit: I thought null was falsy.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment

Comment: This is no excuse.

Comment: To avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: @Turing85 well it does answer the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @Luatic [not in itfs first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76740268/1) (which my comment was aimed at).

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following, `null`-safe alternative:

```
Optional.ofNullable(fullString)
  .orElse("")
  .contains(testStr);
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Ifd0e0)

When `fullStr` is in fact `null` then `""` will be used, and `.contains(...)` will almost always<sup>1</sup> evaluate to `false`.

If we want to always return `false` when `fullStr` is null, we can use:

```
Optional.ofNullable(fullString)
  .map(s -> s.contains(testStr))
  .orElse(false);
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/cUL8nB)

Note that this solution will return `false` when both `fullString` and `testStr` are `null`. I know that `testStr` is guaranteed to be `!= null`, but thought it might be worth mentioning.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>It will evaluate to `true` when `testStr` is `""` as well</sub>

Comment: Or, for the price of just one more character, we have the following functionally-equivalent version: `Optional.ofNullable(fullString).filter(s -> s.contains(testStr)).isPresent();`... Optionals are certainly a versatile tool

Comment: @HomeworkHopper you are right. In this case I feel that a `.orElse("").contains(...)` or `.map( ...contains(...)).orElse(...)` conveys more of the semantics. But that is of course only my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes it's nice to show that there are many ways to approach the same problem. Perhaps some would prefer an entirely different method, such as: `Objects.requireNonNullElse(fullString, "").contains(testString);`. It all comes down to preference

Comment: @HomeworkHopper or just `fullstring != null && fullstring.contains(testStr)` which is simpler than all other variants.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check if a `String` is contained in another `String` in Java?

Of course.

> It would be the opposite of the contains method accomplishes.

Not really. For `a` and `b` both non-null references to `String`s, your hypothetical `a.isContainedBy(b)` is equivalent to `b.contains(a)`.  Which is what you should use.